# Angular 4 access child of child component

Tags: angular

I'm using ngx-charts line chart component which has a timeline inside.
So the structure go like this : MyComponent -> LineChartComponent -> TimelineComponent.

(where LineChartComponent is the component from the library)

Having a reference to LineChartComponent is it possible to execute something like @ViewChild() on this reference to access the TimelineComponent ?

Answer (score 1):

If it's projected, you can use `@ContentChild()`, otherwise you need `LineChartComponent` to make it available.

The better approach would be to use a shared service that you provide at `MyComponent` and inject to `MyComponent` and `TimelineComponent` and use like a message bus to communicate between these two components for example using Observables.

See also https://angular.io/guide/component-interaction#parent-and-children-communicate-via-a-service

Comment: Sure, but the TimelineComponent is also from the library.

Comment: Sorry, not sure what you try to say with that comment. How does that matter?

Comment: I can't inject anything to TimelineComponent because : it is in LineChartComponent and both of them comes from the library.

Comment: What are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: Access a property in TimelineComponent.

Comment: Perhaps you can use `element.nativeElement.querySelector(...)` and update properties on the host element and check if the component takes it up. Otherwise I think you're out of luck.